# Trying to recreate a safe from mainnet into gnosis chain issue

Tags: gnosis-safe

I contacted the support because I'm currently stuck on case 3: https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5267779-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover

The support gave me this instructions to recreate the safe on gnosis chain:
https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741

I just followed then and ended them in this tx hash that executed correctly:
https://blockscout.com/xdai/mainnet/tx/0x87323c3337b9e4198d8d912fd6d03c1b74a9aa623ebcf9f134e28b44334c5317

But seems that the recreated safe it's not the same as the original one:
Original: https://gnosis-safe.io/app/eth:0xd8Cb50Dc901521DA34980D1D6E8cB150E81b26C6/
Recreated: https://gnosis-safe.io/app/gno:0x10f90064b07320c9397cc2d5376e8daed0b59f41/transactions/history

Seems that the same safe was not re-created on gnosis chain but another one. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your case would fall under "Case 3" of https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5267779-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover.

As mentioned in this article the `createProxy` method does not rely on `create2` therefore the address depends on the order in which the proxy was created.

If you need to recover funds reach out to the Gnosis team directly and check if they can help you (there is a low chance that it is possible).

Additional context:

In your case the use of `create2` (via the `createProxyWithNonce` method) would not have changed anything, as your Safe was originally created via the 1.1.1 version of the Safe Factory it. If you compare the bytecode of that factory on mainnet and gnosis chain you will see that there is a slight difference (in the metadata: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/metadata.html). As the address of the Safe depends on the bytecode any change in the bytecode will result in a different address.